# Open downloaded file on Android N using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-7.0-nougat

I've got to fix our App for Android N due to the FileProvider changes. I've basically read all about this topic for the last ours, but no solution found did work out for me.

Here's our prior code which starts downloads from our app, stores them in the `Download` folder and calls an `ACTION_VIEW` intent as soons as the `DownloadManager` tells he's finished downloading:

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Download commplete");

        // Check for our download
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (mDownloadReference == referenceId) {
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(mDownloadReference);
            Cursor c = mDownloadManager.query(query);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String localUri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(localUri);
                    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);

                    if (mimeType != null) {
                        Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        openFileIntent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(Uri.parse(localUri), mimeType);
                        openFileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                        try {
                            mAcme.startActivity(openFileIntent);
                        }
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            // Ignore if no activity was found.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This works on Android M, but breaks on N due to the popular `FileUriExposedException`. I've now tried to fix this by using the `FileProvider`, but I cannot get it to work. It's breaking when I try to get the content URI:

`Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf`

The `localUri` returned from the `DownloadManager` for the file is:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf`

The `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns `/storage/emulated/0` and this is the code for the conversion:

```
File file = new File(localUri);
Log.d(TAG, localUri + " - " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctxt, "my.file.provider", file);
```

From `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="my.file.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

The `file_paths.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_path" path="." />
</paths>
```

And I've tried all values I could find in that xml file. :(

Comment: Make sure that you are on the latest version of the Android Support libraries. If you are, off the cuff, this feels like a bug in the current `FileProvider`.

Comment: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf`. You cannot use that as is. Remove "file://" from it. You have to use a valid file path: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm running on v24.2.1

Comment: @greenapps Man you saved my life! I really hate reduced code example in the official docs. :/

Comment: what is `mDownloadReference`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @greenaps I was able to solve the issue. The local URI retrieved from the `DownlodManager` was prefixed with `file://`. This has to be dropped for the new `FileProvider`:

```
if (localUri.substring(0, 7).matches("file://")) {
    localUri =  localUri.substring(7);
}
File file = new File(localUri);
```

Comment: Please next time you find an answer in a comment invite the poster to post his comment as an answer.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer. I haven't accepted mine yet for that purpose.

Comment: can you post the full answer?

Answer (score 6):

here change in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

change in file path

```
Uri contentUri;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 24){
         contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
              getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    file);
 } else{
         contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
```

Comment: That's not really adding any value as i'm doing that already.

Answer (score 2):

How to get file exact path filename. lower and higher device.

public class RealPathUtil {

```
public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
    String realPath;
    // SDK < API11
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4) and up
    else {
        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri);
    }
    return realPath;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = 0;
    String result = "";
    if (cursor != null) {
        column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri     The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context       The context.
 * @param uri           The Uri to query.
 * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

}

This is exact solution. Just call 
Uri selectedResume = data.getData();
String mediaResumePath = RealPathUtil.getRealPath(this, selectedResume);

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by not automatically opening the file but showing the 'Download complete' notification and then let the Android system open the file when the user clicks on the notification.

To notify the user additionally, I'm showing a Toast when the download is completed.

```
DownloadManager mManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

String url = "your URL";
String filename = "file.pdf";

// Set up the request.
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            .setTitle("Test")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename)
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDescription("Downloading...")
            .setMimeType("application/pdf");

request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
mManager.enqueue(request);
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Download completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be this clearer solution ?

```
Uri uriParser = Uri.parse(downloadedPackageUriString);
File downloadedFile = new File(uriParser.getPath());
```

before

> file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/ZS%20Gac%C3%ADkov%C3%A1.pdf

after

> /storage/emulated/0/Download/ZS Gacíková.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is how I download, save and return a file to the viewmodel :)

interface FileDownloader {
companion object {
private val instance: FileDownloader by lazy {

```
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()

        val downloaderApi = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://exmaple.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
            .create(FileDownloader::class.java)

        downloaderApi
    }

    suspend fun downloadAndSaveFile(
        url: String
    ): File {
        val file = getPdfFile()
        val responseBody = try {
            instance.downloadFile(url)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw FileDownloadException(url, e)
        }
        @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
        try {
            FileOutputStream(file).use { outputStream ->
                responseBody.byteStream().use { inputStream ->
                    inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw FileDownloadException(url, e)
        }
        return file
    }


}

@GET
@Streaming
suspend fun downloadFile(@Url utl: String): ResponseBody
}

fun getPdfFile(): File {
    File(App.appContext.filesDir, "pdfs").apply { mkdirs() }
    return File(App.appContext.filesDir, "tempPDF.pdf")
}

class FileDownloadException(url: String, e: Exception) : Throwable()
```