# Open a file downloaded using download manager Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have used this code to download the pdf file in my app and it works well for all phones but the code I have written to open the downloaded file works well for APK less than 21 but it doesn't for better phones like Samsung S7 etc.

My code for downloading a pdf file:

```
Boolean memoerAvailable = (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED));
if (memoerAvailable) {
  final DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(link));
  request.setTitle("Click to download the book");
  request.setDescription("File is being downloaded...");

  //use download manager to download the clicked book
  request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, ShowbooksActivity.myBooksList.get(ShowbooksActivity.pos).getMpdfName());
  request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(bookWithAdapterActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myfile.jpg");
  final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
  final long queueid = manager.enqueue(request);
```

My code for opening the downloaded file:

```
filetoopen = ls1.get(position);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Download/" + filetoopen);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
try {
  startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an exeption? Try to use FileProvier for API>23.

[Open downloaded file on Android N using FileProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996491/open-downloaded-file-on-android-n-using-fileprovider)

Comment: whenever I try to open any downloaded book,  the app crashes

Comment: Because on API>23 you have to use FileProvider

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                    mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                            url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```